# PDFKit symbols missing from Swift Package error

Tags: dependencies, symbols, swiftpm

I am trying to build a swift package that has a dependency on a framework, but that downstream framework is throwing an error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PDFDocument", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Slice.swift.o
      objc-class-ref in Utility.swift.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PDFPage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Slice.swift.o
      objc-class-ref in Utility.swift.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The downstream framework builds fine in isolation, but when it is added as a dependency to something else it's a pain.

It seems 'PDFKit' from the iOS or macOS SDK is not linked. How would I link that?

I tried adding the following to my code to see if it would make a difference, but it didn't.

```
#if os(macOS) 
import Quartz.PDFKit
#else
import PDFKit
#endif
```

The error suggests PDFKit needs to be listed in my Package.swift file ... ?

EDIT

The error is eliminated if I manually select 'PDFKit' here. However, this instance of Xcode was built with

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

So manually changing things should not be necessary...

[image]

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/undefined-symbols-when-importing-a-package/43177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the [swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/undefined-symbols-when-importing-a-package/43177) I managed to find an answer using [this API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/linkersetting/3112680-linkedframework).

Answer (score 0):

Here was the correct usage for me in Package.swift

#### How to link system framework/library in swift package

```
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "SomeTarget",
      dependencies: [ ... ],
      linkerSettings: [
        .linkedFramework("PDFKit")
      ]
    ),
  ]
```

Note that LinkerSetting has both `.linkedFramework(..)` and `.linkedLibrary(..)`